# How to postpone payment execution in Paypal.

Tags: paypal

I found [this](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) page that tells how to execute a Paypal payment.

It does not say if it is possible to delay the last step of executing the payment with Paypal.

Can it be postponed? It is possible capture payments later with their API, but that does not seem to cover when you send the user through Paypal to authorize the payment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorization & capture (as documented [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/capture-payment/)) is available on PayPal wallet payments as well. As long as you set your `intent` to `authorize`, it will create an authorization.

I.e.

```
{
  "intent":"authorize",
  "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://<return URL here>",
    "cancel_url":"http://<cancel URL here>"
  },
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      },
      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, my issue is that I need the user to authorize the payment that may not be executed for 24 hours. Or, it may be cancelled by the site owner.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. As long as you create and execute the authorization call, you can capture it any time up to 29 days later. The first three days we'll guarantee the capture ('honour period'), and after the first three days, you've got 26 more days to capture the authorization (though we can't guarantee the funds will be there).

Comment: So, when PP notifies me that the user has authorized the transaction, instead of responding immediately, I can store the info and complete the transaction later. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: That's right. Once you have an 'authorization ID' you can come back and capture it hours or days later. We reserve the funds with the issuer for three days ('honour period').

Comment: Thanks PayPal_Robert.